# How to write a partial word of a bold label in italic? R bquote

Tags: r, bold, italic

I would like to change the labels of my graph. ChatGPT etc. gave me this useful command:

```
x_labels <- c(
  bquote(bold("Arabisch gelesen, " ~ italic("Weiß"))),
  bquote(bold("Schwarz, " ~ italic("Weiß")))
)
```

To make the text "Weiß" also in bold, it suggest me this:

```
x_labels <- c(
  bquote(bold("Arabisch gelesen, " ~ bold(italic("Weiß")))),
  bquote(bold("Schwarz, " ~ bold(italic("Weiß"))))
)
```

But if I run it, the labels stay the same, so "Weiß" never appears bold.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider also trying `ggtext::element_markdown()` which will give you a lot more control over the appearance of the labels.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bolditalic`. For example, let's make your second *Weiß* bold italic and leave the first as italic:

```r
x_labels <- c(
  bquote(bold("Arabisch gelesen, " ~ italic("Weiß"))),
  bquote(bold("Schwarz, ") ~ bolditalic("Weiß"))
)
```

Testing, we get:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x = c('a', 'b'), y = 1:2), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = x_labels) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

Comment: This just worked perfectly, thank you so much

Comment: `quote()` can be used instead of `bquote()` here. But in any case be careful because this is undocumented use AFAIU, what is documented is the use of an "expression vector", so `expression(bold("Arabisch gelesen, " ~ italic("Weiß")), bold("Schwarz, ") ~ bolditalic("Weiß"))` might be more appropriate.